# Good/Simple webservice which can be consumed using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I was looking for Good/Simple webservice which can be consumed using asp.net but I can't a find a free webservice that can be used with asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html) has a pretty good bunch of (free) API's.

Not sure what you mean by "webservice that can be used with asp.net".

Most web services expose their API's via XML/JSON/RSS etc, which is platform independant.

The Music API is a pretty simple one, they expose REST web services (both JSON and XML).

You simply need to construct a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to their API and parse the data.

Comment: @MuraliVijay CSK - check out http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/285/httpwebrequest/ it's an extremely simple example of a http web request using .net.